# (VBA) Populating drop down menu in Excel depending on the value of another dropdown?

Tags: excel, vba

What is the best approach to produce two drop down menus, where the contents of the second are depedent on the value chosen from the first?

Would the second drop down just be created blank and each time I select a new value from the first drop down I "overwrite" some sort of attribute referring to the second drop down? Or should I re-create the second drop-down menu every time the first dropdown is clicked?

Any code snippets are most welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what sort of dropdown you are using. If you are using data validation to have an in-cell dropdown then you can set the source of the second dropdown cell to an indirect function then you have your data in named ranges which reference the first dropdown.
More info here:
http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal02.html

This can get tedious creating all the named ranges if you have a large amount of data in the first dropdown.

I have also done this in a userform with VBA.

```
Public Branches() As String
Public Function List_Branch_Set(lngRegion As String) As Long
    Dim lngAllBranches As Long
    Dim lngReg As String
    Dim lngBranches As Long
    Dim lngIdx As Long
    Dim rw As Long
    lngAllBranches = Sheets("sheet1").Range("C1").Value
    lngBranches = CountBranches(lngRegion)
    If lngBranches > 0 Then
        ReDim Branches(lngBranches - 1)
        For rw = 2 To lngAllBranches + 1
            lngReg = Sheets("sheet1").Cells(rw, 2).Value
            If lngReg = lngRegion Then
                Branches(lngIdx) = Sheets("sheet1").Cells(rw, 1).Value
                lngIdx = lngIdx + 1
            End If
        Next rw
    End If
    List_Branch_Set = lngBranches
End Function
```

My data is then stored on sheet1 in the format:
Branch       Region

The function CountBranches() counts the number of rows in this list which match the selected region. Then you need a trigger on the first cbo.

```
Private Sub cboRegion_Change()
    Dim lngNum As Long
    Me.cboBranch.Clear
    lngNum = List_Branch_Set(NullHandleText(Me.cboRegion))
    If lngNum <> 0 Then
        Me.cboBranch.List = Branches
    End If
End Sub
```